# Django stringformat i

Tags: django

I have a dropdown list on a page. When a user selects a value, the index of the option is stored in the database. When the user retrieves the page, the previous stored value should be selected by default.

This is how I render the selected option in the template:

```
{% if report.tag == forloop.counter|stringformat:"i" %}
    selected="selected"
{% endif %}
```

The for loop contains the list of values, `report.tag` contains the value previously selected by the user.

My question is: when comparing the values in the template I have to use `forloop.counter|stringformat:"i"`. If `forloop.counter` is used, the comparison will not work. Why is that?

```
// if never registers, even though foorloop.counter 
// outputs the same value as forloop.counter|stringformat:"i"
{% if report.tag == forloop.counter %}
```

Comment: Presumably `report.tag` returns a string, rather than an int.

Comment: comparing a string vs int?

Comment: @DanielRoseman & Sayse you are right, thanks!